# How to install Python on Mac through Pyenv?

Tags: python, macos, openssl, pyenv

I want to install python 3.4.2 on Mac 10.15.1

I have run:
*$ pyenv install 3.4.2*

but appears the error:

> Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS

searching i have found this link with [common build problems](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems)

I have installed openssl through homebrew

*$ brew install openssl*

and

*$ xcode-select --install*

and tried with two other flagged commands:

*$ CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pyenv install -v 3.4.2*

*$ CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64 pyenv install -v 3.4.2*

but terror persist.

Here are the 10 last log lines:

```
(cd /Users/albertosanmartinmartinez/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.4.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
  case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python.exe -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS
```

Anybody could help please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this exact issue on my machine too: 10.15.4 (19E287) macOS Catalina